# How to set the colors of an Options Menu

Tags: android, menu, themes

I have an older app that uses `openOptionsMenu()` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to bring up a menu. Yes, I know this is obsolete, and replacing it with a more modern UI is on my short list of things to do, but I have a problem I'm hoping to solve today.

Basically, if the entire menu doesn't fit on the screen, there is a "More" item at the end that opens a popup when you select it. It worked perfectly on older versions of Android, but now it looks like this:

[image: Android bad options menu]

Any time I try to look up "options menu colors" or "options menu theme", the search results always lead me to ActionBar or Toolbar. But my app doesn't use either of these.

Any hints as to how I control the appearance of an old options menu?

---

Relevant source code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, MENU_ABOUT, 0, R.string.About)
      .setAlphabeticShortcut('a')
      .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
    menu.add(0, MENU_BASIC, 0, R.string.Basic)
      .setAlphabeticShortcut('b')
      .setIcon(R.drawable.calc);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SCI, 0, R.string.Scientific)
      .setAlphabeticShortcut('s')
      .setIcon(R.drawable.science);
    menu.add(0, MENU_TAPE, 0, R.string.Tape)
      .setAlphabeticShortcut('t')
      .setIcon(R.drawable.tape);
    menu.add(0, MENU_HELP, 0, R.string.Help)
      .setAlphabeticShortcut('h')
      .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);
    menu.add(0, MENU_PREFERENCES, 0, R.string.Preferences)
      .setAlphabeticShortcut('p')
      .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specy the background color and text color in styles. ie

res -> values -> styles.xml file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:itemBackground">#ffffff</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
```

Comment: Sunnuva gun. The parent theme was actually `android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar`, but the principle holds. Why did that theme not have contrasting colors by default? And why did it work before? Just for fun, I set the theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and left out the background and text color and the result was black text and a transparent background. What a mess. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You can use your application parent Theme instead and Try. If you want to change the text color only then you can remove the android:itemBackground element from style.